# What is wrong with my attempt of $0 \lt w \lt \frac{\pi}{6}$ then $w \csc w$ is?

Tags: proof-verification, trigonometry

> For $0 \lt w \lt \frac{\pi}{6}$,  the value of  $ w  \csc w $ is
>
> A) less than $ \frac{\pi}{6}$
>
> B) greater than $ \frac{\pi}{6}$
>
> C) less than $\frac{\pi}{3}$
>
> D) greater than $ \frac{\pi}{3}$

I know from L'hospital rule that $ \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{h}{\sin h} = 1 $
and $\sin \frac{\pi}{6} = 0.5 $, thus

$ w  \csc w $ goes from $1$ to $\frac{\pi}{3}$. (Open interval)

Thus answer should be (B and C) greater than $\frac{\pi}{6}$ and less than $\frac{\pi}{3}$.

But the answer is only C.

Comment: This appears to be a case of looking for the "best answer," whatever that this. If this was given to you by an instructor rather than taken from a textbook, you may wish to bring it up with them.

Comment: @Brian I edited the tag recently maybe it newer got saved. Mobile app is difficult to operate.

Comment: @Brian you should write this as answer! I will accept it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Per the comments, this appears to be a case of looking for the "best answer," whatever that this. If this was given to you by an instructor rather than taken from a textbook, you may wish to bring it up with them.